# Online Payment Gateway for UAE (Dubai) and Dubai Merchant account

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway

I am not sure if this is the correct place to ask this, but I am hoping that there are some developers here who will be able to answer this question.

I am developing an online payment solution for a client in Dubai, and my usual online payment gateways which I use are not an option for this project as they either do not accept the currency or require a merchant account outside of Dubai.

Do you know of a payment gateway that I would be able to use/integrate with? Similar to SagePay/WorldPay/Paypal

Many Thanks!

Comment: possibly, but then if other developers have done what I am wanting to do then they will know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the UAE, there is a sort of monopoly when it comes to card processing. Look-up 'network llc' , its a dubai based company (a subsidiary of emirates nbd bank), they seem to have control over all credit card billing machines in the UAE.

You can also try Mastercard Internet Gateway Services Australia. A lot of big UAE companies (Gulf News, Air Arabia) use MIGS Australia to process online payments.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I found a payment gateway called CyberSource which might be able to fit my needs.